# How to assign numbers to the groups?

Tags: postgresql, grouping

I can use `row_number()` function to assign numbers to the rows inside groups:

```
SELECT
  a.docn as agreement,
  o.id as order_id,
  (ROW_NUMBER() over (PARTITION BY a.id, o.id, ois.consumed_period )) as group_id
  ...
```

[image]

**but how to assign numbers to the groups?**

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems found the answer. The [doc](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/functions-window.html):

> All of the functions listed in Table 9.60 depend on the sort ordering specified by the ORDER BY clause of the associated window definition. **Rows that are not distinct when considering only the ORDER BY columns are said to be peers.** The four ranking functions (including cume_dist) are defined so that **they give the same answer for all peer rows.**

```
select
  a.docn as agreement,
  o.id as order_id,
  (dense_rank() over (PARTITION BY a.id, o.id ORDER BY ois.consumed_period )) as group_id,
```

Here I use `dense_rank` to  `Rank the current row within its partition`**`without gaps`** and use `order by` to **`create peers`**.
Thus `dense_rank` assign next number for each *distinct* value of `ois.consumed_period`

[image]